# Custom display of posts of Facebook, Twitter, Linkedi and Google+ on your website

Tags: php, facebook, twitter, google-plus, linkedin-api

Is it possible to shows posts, feeds etc in a customized manner on your website? For example if I don't want to use the plugins they provide to embed on your website which show posts in a rectangular box I want to show posts from these social media sites in different manner. For reference please visit this [website](http://design.unipro.co.in/website/isbm-static/) and scroll down to section below Latest News and Testimonials you will find Facebook, Twitter, LinkedIn and Google+ with Lorem Ipsum text. It seems like this website has also not implemented this feature (don't know if its possible with all social sites) but I am asking if you need to implement something like this is this possible? I have to implement it on a PHP website, if that helps. Thanks for your help in advance.

Comment: At least for twitter it is possible and I am pretty sure all of those service have API in PHP which allow you to fetch data.

I did it for twitter in Symfony 3 for my portfolio using the bundle endroid/twitter-bundle.

Comment: This is very broad in terms of responses that you might potentially get

Comment: @Matthieu :- Thanks, can you please provide links to that tutorial on how to do it for Twitter.

Comment: @Takarii :- Thanks for response. And I know that but I'm looking for potentiality of this tasks means if someone has implemented such a thing previously or may be links to proper tutorials can be really helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Although you're asking for something different than embedding, I still believe what you're looking for is "Embedding posts". Most social sites do not want you to rebuild their stream experience and put it somewhere else -- additionally, most content policies on these sites prohibits you from caching or storing posts because it can easily become a privacy issue. Finally, if you're pulling a lot of posts, frequently, from these services, you will encounter API call limits.

The following resources should get you started with properly embedding posts so you don't have to worry about how you're caching:

- [Google+](https://developers.google.com/+/web/embedded-post/)
- [Facebook](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/embedded-posts)
- [Twitter](https://dev.twitter.com/web/embedded-tweets)

If you (really, really) wanted to build out your own solution you should do it client-side in JavaScript, not in PHP. For this, you would need to use the following APIs:

- Google+ uses the [Activity API](https://developers.google.com/+/web/api/rest/latest/activities)
- Facebook has the [Graph/Feed API](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/user/feed/)
- Twitter has the [Search/Get Tweets API](https://dev.twitter.com/rest/reference/get/search/tweets) pass from%3A[username] to get specific user Tweets

If you were to try doing this in PHP, it would be easier using client libraries and starting from sample code.

- [Google+ PHP example](https://github.com/googleplus/gplus-quickstart-php)
- [Facebook PHP client library](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/php/)
- [Twitter PHP client libraries](https://dev.twitter.com/overview/api/twitter-libraries#php)

Make sure that you're following the content policies of the various sites you're aggregating. In other words, if you're doing something like caching the results in a MySQL database pulled using your PHP script, invalidate the cache every 3600 seconds and every time a post is no longer retrieved from your API calls.